# Android DataBinding / BindingAdapter Error: { missing return statement }

Tags: android, android-binding-adapter

Android DataBinding / BindingAdapter Error: An error is thrown: error: missing return statement when passing a function to BindingAdapter (block: () -> Unit).

**BindingAdapter.kt**

```
@BindingAdapter("click")
fun LottieAnimationView.click(block: () -> Unit) {
    setOnClickListener {
        block()
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.veldan.ViewModel" />
</data>

<View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        click="@{() -> viewModel.viewFun()}"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"   />

<View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        click="@{() -> viewModel.viewFun()}"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"   />
```

**ViewModel.kt**

```
class ViewModel() {
     viewFun(){
        // logic
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### SOLUTION 1:

Use **Field syntax**

---

- Function syntax: ❌

### | click = "@{ () -> viewModel.viewFun() }"

- Field syntax: ✅

### | click = "@{ viewModel.viewFun }"

---

### SOLUTION 2:

Use **Lambda**

### | ViewModel.kt

```
class ViewModel() {
    val viewFun: () -> Unit = {
        // logic
     }
}
```

**Lambda** - works well when block with parameters.

### | block with parameters

```
@BindingAdapter("click")
fun LottieAnimationView.click(block: (Param1, Param2, ...) -> Unit) {
    setOnClickListener {
        block()
    }
}
```

---